# Is there a difference between Return and func()=

Tags: .net, vb.net, syntax

Is there any difference between the following:

```
public function returnString() as string
  return "string"
end function
```

and

```
public function returnString() as string
  returnString = "string"
end function
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No there isn't any difference in terms of emitted IL. In this specific case the same gets baked into the resulting assembly. The first looks more *C-sharpish* while the second is more *VB-ish*. It's a matter of a personal VB.NET coding style preference.

This being said there is a crucial difference: the [Return statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2e34641s.aspx) returns the control immediately whereas in the second case allows for any lines following the assignment to be executed.

And my .2¢ on the matter: always use the `Return` statement.

Comment: It emits the same IL *in that case*, but not in the general case. You should probably make that clear in your answer, or it might mislead some people...

Comment: Actually I just checked: it *doesn't* emit the same IL. The "VB-ish" version stores the string, and reloads it before returning (it inserts a `stloc.0` and a `ldloc.0` between the `ldstr` and the `ret`). So it actually emits 2 useless instructions... which are probably optimized away by the JIT